# Problem while adding a route to F5 BigIp version 9

Tags: routing, f5-big-ip

I want to add a route for outbound traffic from BigIp v9. I have WANem machine configured which simulates the network traffic and want to add this as a router between BigIp9 virtual server and Client. This WANem is running on Knoppix 5. I have tried below ways to add:

1. Adding route by BigIp GUI from menu Netwok -> Route
2. I created a pool having member as my WANem machin IP and created a wildcard virtual server which uses the pool.

However I am not able to see the traffic going through WANem machin to client.

Please suggest me any workable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few things going on here, and the answer depends upon what you're trying to accomplish. For a flow like this:

```
Client --> Router --> BigIP Virtual Server
```

The BigIP itself actually doesn't need a route at all: it has a feature called 'auto lasthop', which simply means it keeps track of the last MAC address that sent the flow to the Virtual Serer, and it'll send it back to that MAC by default.

So to try and answer your question I'll make two assumptions you are either wanting to do:

1) Source traffic from the BigIP itself (for DNS, NTP, etc for example)
2) Handle traffic sourced from pool members behind the BigIP. 
3) or, more likely, both #1 and #2 above :)

The flow now looks like:

```
Client --> Router --> BigIP Virtual Server --> Pool Members
```

Basically, if you've got a default route set up on the BigIP (using your #1 method above) and your pool members point to the BigIP floating IP address as *their* default route, flows will behave as you expect. If your pool members point to another router for their default gateway, you'll need to enable SNAT on your virtual server so the pool members will send the traffic back to the BigIP as opposed to their default gateway.

There are a few other, more advanced, configurations available (multiple gateways, multiple server vlans behind BigIP, etc.), but it sounds like you're on the right track.

Btw, tcpdump is your friend :).

For more questions I'd check [F5 DevCentral](http://devcentral.f5.com/) out; chances are good your exact question has been answered there already.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like maybe the pool members need to have their default gateway or route tables updated as well. The F5 is probably routing through the target device, but the return packets are probably going directly to the F5 and bypassing the target device during the responses.

F5 solves this by using SNAT automap. Alternatively, you could look for a setting like this on the target device to resolve the problem.